Evans (6.4.3) Proof of Harnack Inequality, How do we get extra derivatives on $v$?
In Evans' Partial Differential Equations Section 6.4.3 Evans shows that (with $b^i = c = 0$) a solution $u > 0 \in C^2$ to
$$Lu = -\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a^{ij}u_{x_ix_j} = 0 \quad \text{in $U$}$$
satisfies the Harnack Inequality for any compactly embedded subset $V\subset\subset U$. Namely that
$$ \sup_{V}u \leq C \inf_{V}u$$
for some constant $C$. In order to do so, one verifies that by defining $v = \log(u)$, one can show that
$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a^{ij}v_{x_ix_j} + a^{ij}v_{x_i}v_{x_j} = 0 \quad \text{in U}.$$
In future steps, Evans defines
$$ w:= \sum_{i,j}^{n}a^{ij}v_{x_i}v_{x_j}.$$
He then computes the second derivatives of $w$, $w_{x_k,x_l}$. Notably,
$$ w_{x_k,x_l} = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}2a^{ij}v_{x_ix_kx_l}v_{x_j} + 2a^{ij}v_{x_ix_k}v_{x_jx_l}+ R,$$
where $R$ is a remainder term. My question is as follows: if $u \in C^2$, how did we justify the existence up to a fourth derivative on $v$? This is used to justify later steps that get to the actual conclusion of the proof, but I want to know how it was justified in the first place.

$a_{ij}$s are also assumed to be smooth in this proof so thm 3 of 6.3 applies

(Turning comment into answer.) In addition to $b^i=c=0$, Evans also assumes $a^{ij}$ are smooth. So 'elliptic regularity' tells us that the solution is not just $C^2$, but smooth on the interior of $U$. Specifically, we can use Theorem 3 of section 6.3, which I copy below:

THEOREM 3 (infinite differentiability in the interior). Assume
$$ a^{ij}, b^i, c \in C^\infty(U) \quad (i,j=1,\dots,n)$$
and
$$ f \in C^\infty(U).$$
Suppose $u\in H^1(U)$ is a weak solution of the elliptic PDE
$$ Lu = f \quad \text{in } U.$$
Then
$$ u \in C^\infty(U).$$

